# HTML Anchor not following relative link

Tags: html, href

I have two local pages, one called Index.html
https://pastebin.com/wA1Y1WC0

And another called biographies.html
https://pastebin.com/PBeW2hz8

The folder structure is Project1 for the root, which contains Index.html and a folder there called members that contains biographies.html.

When I follow the link:

```
 a href="members/biographies.html/#John_Lewis"
```

and then try

```
a href="../Index.html"
```

The link back to Index does not work.

However, if I open biographies.html directly the link back to Index does work. I am restricted to using relative paths, and I have tried changing the path on the biographies page multiple times, including ../Index.html AND /Project1/Index.html to no avail. Can anyone give me a pointer as to why this doesn't work? I've asked my teacher and we are both stumped. Thanks!

Comment: `a href="members/biographies.html/#John_Lewis"` should be `a href="members/biographies.html#John_Lewis"` You have an extra slash. Not the problem, just FYI

Comment: I guess there is no need to slash before #John_Lewis

Comment: Updating your code to use ../Index.html works for me.

Comment: If you are running this locally, what do you think `href="/Project/Index.html"` is going to link to? It would be the root of your file system. For file system served pages, you  should use relative links as @JasonB suggested

Comment: If you are not running through a web server such as Apache or IIS (you'd be using protocols http:// or https:// in your address bar) and instead are just opening up the files directly in the browser (you'd likely see file:// instead of http/https in the address bar) you should not use "/" in front of "/Project".

Comment: One useful way for debugging these types of situations is to look at the source code. In most browsers if you click on a non-working link in the source code it should attempt to redirect you to the specified link. You could then verify what is wrong with the address by what it now shows in the address bar.

Comment: After removing the slash after biographies.html and using Jason and Juans' suggestion made it work. That is awesome! Thank you all for your help.

Comment: @JuanMendes please post your comment as answer

Answer (score 0):

When you serving from the file system, a link to `/file.html` means to look in the root of the drive for a `file.html`.

When dealing with a webpage served by the file system, you should only use relative links.

You also had a stray slash after the file name, remove that

```
/root/Index.html => <a href="members/biographies.html#John_Lewis">
/root/members/biographies.html => <a href="../Index.html">
```